# I want to display animated text using <ScrollAnimation> but i see a blank page

Tags: reactjs, animation

I already installed react-animate-on-scroll and animate.css i also tried Rotate component. I want to render animated text in col-3 how can achive this

```js
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ScrollAnimation from 'react-animate-on-scroll';

 
 const Animation = () => (

<ScrollAnimation animateBounce="bounceIn">

<p>Text bounces in on scroll</p>

</ScrollAnimation>

)


ReactDOM.render( <Animation />, document.getElementById("col-3"));
```

```html
   


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

   

<body>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-1">
   </div>
 
<div class="col-2">
 </div>
 
<div id="col-3">
 </div>
 
 
 

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: given code doesnot work

Comment: It's work I'm just write animation part

Answer (score 0):

```js
  <ScrollAnimation animateIn="rotateIn" offset={800}>
    <h1>Rotating!</h1>
  </ScrollAnimation>
```

`offset` is optional, it just doesn't animate if you open the page and the animation element is not below the offset from the bottom of the page (which is 150 pixels by default).

You can see the full version on https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hugle-h2fh5?file=/src/Animation.js